# Why was my Magento development question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, questions

I [asked a question here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/281894/why-is-magento-that-much-difficult-and-what-tasks-will-i-be-working-on-as-a-ma), because [I didn't get any suitable answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525118/is-magento-development-too-difficult-for-a-junior-developer). It got 5200 + views with good answer, but mine was closed **without any** answer. Why did this happen? How could I have asked a similar question that would not be closed?

I asked the users who closed the question, but none of them gave an answer that I understood. What should I do now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that [Is Magento development too difficult for a junior developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525118/is-magento-development-too-difficult-for-a-junior-developer) from Stack Overflow was asked in 2010 - nearly five years ago.  The sites were different back then. On Stack Overflow, 5000 views over four years isn't a big number.  The question was also closed as not constructive (old reasons) in '11.

Using a question from 2010 that has since been closed is not a good basis for asking another question on a Stack Exchange site.

You have two questions within the post:

> My qestion is why is it difficult for a developer who hasnt worked on Zend framework ?

This question is *completely* developer dependent.  It may be easy for one developer and hard for another. It cannot be answered with anything other than a poll of opinions and experiences.

When questions have such a format and can be answered by "Because Zend sucks" it means that there is something that the question needs to do to guide the answers to *good* quality answers rather than a mindless poll that inspires poor answers.

The second question:

> What tasks will i be working on as a Magento Developer?

That depends completely on where one gets employment as a Magento developer. The tasks at one place may be completely different than another.  This again speaks to the question being a poll and you would be getting many conflicting answers - which doesn't make for good answer content on the site.

Comment: Glad you answered. Other people kept me sending from site A to site B, from site B to C , and so on. Thanks!!! :)

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com its a frustrating thing when that happens. It often comes when people don't completely understand the scope of the other site.

Comment: I hope some one expert in magento could also answer my question precisely here.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com when you are looking to poll for opinions and experiences, you might try looking at another site format.  Stack Exchange focused on Q&A, and in doing so made the poll type questions hard to answer well with good content (to get some background on this [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6743/40980)). You might try asking in the chat rooms associated with http://magento.stackexchange.com/ (though looking at them, they're not that active) - chat room rules are much more relaxed than main site.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com that is why I recommended you ask on meta to begin with: comments don't provide sufficient space to explain this and being bounced around aimlessly helps nobody. The goal here is to learn how to ask questions to get the information you need. I know this can be frustrating to new users (I have asked my fair share of bad questions on SE) but once you understand how to ask, this community is an amazing resource.

Answer (score 7):

There are three things to keep in mind about the other question:

1. It was asked on Stack Overflow which has different question scope and guidelines than Programmers, so using it as an example of "but it was on-topic!" is invalid.
2. It was asked four and a half years ago, and site rules and guidelines change over time. While Stack Overflow has not had nearly as much change in this area as Programmers, it has still evolved. Pointing to *any* old question on the first few Stack Exchange sites (SO, Prog, SuperUser, ServerFault, etc) as evidence of being on-topic is suspect and should be approached carefully.
3. The question was closed anyway, several years ago.

---

Your question has two problems:

> My qestion is why is it difficult for a developer who hasnt worked on Zend framework ?

Subjective. This is a question about the *developer*, not the *technology*. I have personally seen many cases where one developer easily picked up a new technology where another developer struggled.

Not only can we not answer because we do not know the developers involved, any answer would be isolated to those specific developers. The Q&A format is designed to be applicable to *many* people, not one or two: Stack Exchange is essentially a repository of questions and answers that people can find from Google *and get an answer*. What do I, random Internet searcher care, if person X had a hard time learning technology Y? I do not care, that does not apply to me.

> And 2nd one : What tasks will i be working on as a Magento Developer?

Ask your supervisor, not the Internet. While someone may be able to say "Magento developers commonly perform tasks X, Y, and Z" perhaps your position is only X, or Z, or sweeping the floors because you got hired to allocate funds due to budget games (I have seen stuff like this happen, seriously).

We cannot predict the future any more or less than anyone else. Just like the weatherman, we might be able to make educated guesses but *nobody knows for sure*. That question is not objectively answerable.

---

I think your questions are answerable, just not in the Stack Exchange Q&A format. You are really looking for:

- Tutorials. This will give you a taste of Magento to gauge its difficulty *for you*. Personally, I can read a tutorial and get a decent idea of how difficult a particular technology is. This may also help with "what tasks will I be working on?" because tutorials often cover the common tasks of a technology once they get past "hello world."
- Blog posts. If you want to learn about a technology and all the subjective gooey bits that go along with it, read blogs on the topic. People will talk about their experiences, what they had a hard time with and why. They may make comments about "I was developing yet another X because that is what we do with technology Y" which helps answer your second question.

I think if you read good questions and answers on Stack Exchange and compare with good tutorials and blog posts, you will see that the formats are utterly different. Each resource has its strengths and weaknesses and they compliment each other.

Comment: Finally you answered on **meta** . No problem , at least you didnt send me from Site B to C.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com on P.SE we've often been the recipients of people bouncing others to here. We really do understand your frustration and would rather not perpetuate the "go somewhere else" if we can avoid it. If you stop by [chat] (the whiteboard) for any length of time, you'll likely see a chat bot that notifies us of such suggestions from Stack Overflow so that we can try to prevent these suggestions before they are acted on (and possibly inform the people who are making these suggestions about the scope of Programmers.SE so they don't make the same mistake again).

Comment: I would also add that as long as someone is coherent and works with us, we are generally willing to help in return. Communities only succeed when all parties work together.